# how can i get a specific number(for example an stock price) from a web page

Tags: javascript, php, python

I want to get stock price from this site: http://en.tsetmc.com/.
There is a page that tell us all price in this stocks:
http://en.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=121C1111

I tried to get this page content by this code:

```
$address ="http://en.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=121C1111";
    $page = file_get_contents($address);
```

but page send this error

> General Error Detected
>
> Please Try Later

It's the only idea that i have to get data and manipulate it later to get prices.

but I know that there is a better way to get this price.

I want to create an online portfolio manager for school project, and i really need to get stock prices.
I know nothing about Javascript or python and use php to handle it, but if they give me a solution I'll be thankful for them and you.

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That websites' data is loaded via ajax request.

You can access it like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://en.tsetmc.com/tse/data/TradeLastDayData3.aspx?CComVal=&CSecVal=&HEven=0&RefID=0');   //returns json values


$values = json_decode($content,true);   // put json into asso. array


print_r($values);  //acccess your data via array
```

Comment: you mean I use data that this links give me to find every price by searching string? or there is a better way with ajax?
I Just start to read what can I do in w3schools but if you have a better idea I'll appreciate

Comment: How you find that address in the website. is it possible to get something like that for every stock?

Comment: I found that address by opening that website in chrome or firefox, pressing F12 and then reloading. Then check out the Network data.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should find a [webservice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) or a similar [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) that lets you query stock prices. This is much easier, efficient and reliable than retrieving the contents of a web page and parsing it.

It will provides you with the data that you are looking for in a pre-defined format such XML or JSON, that you can read from your PHP code.

You can have a look at that question to find such an API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304107/a-good-api-to-get-stock-or-indexes-price-for-free

Answer (score 0):

Probably the website blocks this kind of request. If you manage to get the page programmatically, you have to do a DOM search.
But it would be even simpler if you find a webservice that provides this information with an API. 
The problem with DOM search is that if they change a comma in the html, probably your program will not work anymore and you have to update it everytime.